# Access form cannot access previous form variable

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a form which have referenced to previous form variable in the following code. I have change the scope to Public for the variable `WorkflowName`, however, error still happened.

```
Form 1: 

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public WorkflowName As String

Private Sub btn_CreditControlEmail_Click()
    WorkflowName = "Email to Credit Control"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "WorkFlow Email Preview"
End Sub
  
Form 2: 
Option Compare Database
Dim frmPrevious As Form
Dim WorkflowName As String

Private Sub btn_ToOutlook_Click()

    'update workflow status to Renewal Table
    MsgBox frmPrevious![WorkflowName]
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm
End Sub
```

However, when run to second form

```
MsgBox frmPrevious![WorkflowName]
```

The following error happened.

[image: The error message]

In watching the value of frmPrevious in second form, I can see the "WorkflowName" value of frmPrevious.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the public variable in a standard module. Then you will have access to it from anywhere in the code via `ModuleName.WorkflowName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refere to a variable in another form you can't use frmPrevious![WorkflowName], because that refers to a field in the first form that does not exist.

But use this: a dot and without brackets:

```
MsgBox frmPrevious.WorkflowName
```

Edit:

Another way to do this, and get the Intelisense to work, is by using the Form_ syntax.
Lets say Form 1 is named "WorkflowStart"

```
MsgBox Form_WorkflowStart.WorkflowName
```

Comment: But I can't see the WorkflowName prompt out in intellisense.

Comment: You'r right, it doesn't. Because it only shows the properties of the form variable frmPrevious not the form itself.